# Get a count of items by type per shift

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having difficulty getting a standard query to do its job...I'm sure I'm missing something silly.

I have a table with two columns that is used for this query - the table is called "calls", and the two fields that I use is "shiftID" and "type".
(Type is a lookup field and will contain 1 of 2 fixed values)

All I need the query to do is count for each shift id the amount of times the two fixed values occured - so the result will look something like this:

```
| shiftID | Type1 | Type2 |
---------------------------
| 131011  |   5   |   2   |
---------------------------
| 131012  |   7   |   6   |
---------------------------
| 131013  |   1   |   3   |
---------------------------
```

Any help will be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: It's always best to show an example pf what you have tried.  Otherwise, we will just be guessing and might lead you down the wrong path.

Comment: What are the 2 possible fixed values for the `Type` field?  Is the field numeric or text data type?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: select shiftId, sum(type1),sum(type2) from calls group by shiftId
if I misunderstand your problem please comment...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can arrive at the desired result.

Assuming a dataset like this:

```
ShiftID  Type
-------  -----------
131011   fixedvalue1
131012   fixedvalue1
131013   fixedvalue2
...      ...
```

you could first transform it this way:

```
SELECT
  ShiftID,
  IIF(Type = 'fixedvalue1', 1, 0) AS Type1,
  IIF(Type = 'fixedvalue2', 1, 0) AS Type2
FROM calls
```

That would give you the following row set:

```
ShiftID  Type1  Type2
-------  -----  -----
131011   1      0
131012   1      0
131013   0      1
...      ...    ...
```

For every `ShiftID` now there are two columns, `Type1` and `Type2` a 1 in one of them a 0 in the other. If you group this result set by `ShiftID` and aggregate (SUM) both columns, you'll get counts of each of the two fixed types per `ShiftID`:

```
SELECT
  ShiftID,
  SUM(IIF(Type = 'fixedvalue1', 1, 0)) AS Type1,
  SUM(IIF(Type = 'fixedvalue2', 1, 0)) AS Type2
FROM calls
GROUP BY ShiftID
```